# Field with query should not be blank

Tags: symfony

How do I add validation constraints "Field is required" in symfony2 PostType class? Any suggestions? I am new in SF2 and I'm just editing what has been done by previous developer.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class BlogPostType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {

        $blogPostCategories = BlogPostCategoryQuery::create()
            ->filterByBlogPost($builder->getData())
            ->find();

        $categoryIds = array();
        foreach ($blogPostCategories as $blogPostCategory) {
            $categoryIds[] = $blogPostCategory->getCategory()->getId();
        }

        $queryOptions = array(
            'option_status' => Categorypeer::STATUS_ACTIVE,
            'option_category_ids' => $categoryIds
        );

        $categories = CategoryQuery::create()
            ->filterActiveCategoriesByOptions($queryOptions)
            ->find();


                $builder->add('category_ids', 'model', array(
        'label' => 'Category',
        'mapped' => false,
        'class' => 'Deal\MainBundle\Model\Category',
        'query' => CategoryQuery::create()
            ->filterActiveCategoriesByOptions()
            ->orderByName(),
        'property' => 'name',
        'empty_value' => 'Select categories',
        'empty_data' => null,
        'required' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'data' => $categories,
        'constraints'   => array(
            new NotBlank(array(
                'message' => 'Your message can not be blank! Ouch!'
            )),
        )
    ));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should set `required => true` for this type from the parent form when calling (that's the form type that uses your `BlogPostType`):

```
$formBuilder->add('whatever', BlogPostType::class, ['required' => true]);
```

Also, you could set `required = true` by default for `BlogPostType`:

```
class BlogPostType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'required' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jlacsonph Can you post how you implemented what I wrote above?

Comment: I check your code and it still doesnt work. please see my updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `constraints` key. Like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array(
            'required'      => true,
            'constraints'   => array(
                new NotBlank(array(
                    'message' => 'Your message can not be blank! Ouch!'
                )),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

do not forget to add uses:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
```

Comment: You wrong with `'constraints' => new NotBlank`. Constraints key must be an array. Look carefully in my example

Comment: I does not see that `'constraints'` key in your code is an array